# Simple integration: $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

Consider the integral $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ then as a Riemann integral it diverges, also as a Lebesgue integral it is $\infty$. However,

for a moment forget $0 \in [-1,1]$ and "integrate":
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \left. -\frac{1}{x} \right|_{-1}^1 = -2$$

Is there a way that one can make sense of this correspondence? Or it is completely absurd...

Answer (score 6):

It makes sense as an integral from -1 to 1 that bypasses the origin in the complex plane, e.g. by moving above it.

Comment: I think a common thing to do is to take the average of two bypasses: a tiny semicircle that bypasses above and a tiny semicircle that bypasses below, and then take the limit as the radius goes to zero. (but since this integrand is analytic, everything works out the same here)

Answer (score 5):

The anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is $-\frac{1}{x}$ when $x\ne 0$.  Inasmuch as the integration limits include the singularity point $x=0$, the anti-derivative is not $-\frac{1}{x}$.

And attempting to split the integral into two improper Riemann integrals leads to the result

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon_1\to 0^{+}}\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon_1}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx+\lim_{\epsilon_2\to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon_2}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon_1\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon_1}-1\right)+\lim_{\epsilon_2\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon_2}-1\right)\\\\
&=\infty
\end{align}$$

even if interpreting the integral as a Cauchy Principal value with $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$.

Comment: Wait a second, why would you say $\lim_{\epsilon_1 \to 0^{-}}$ when the bounds of the integral are from $-1$ to $-\epsilon_1$. Since $\epsilon_1$ is assumed to be negative, then $-\epsilon_1$ would be positive, so the bound of the integral would include the point $0$ which is what you are trying to avoid doing

Comment: @askask Nice catch.  +1 Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary) is: if $f \colon \left[a,b\right] \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function and $F$ is a primitive of $f$ in $\left[a,b\right]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x = F(b)-F(a)$.

Your computation is invalid because $1/x^2$ is not continuous on $\left[-1,1\right]$, in fact, is not defined for $x=0$. And no matter what (real) value you pick for $f(0)$, $f$ won't be continuous and you can't apply the FTC. If you're integrating on $[-1,1]$ then you're not *really* ignoring $0$.

Comment: Just to make a point very clear: There are non-continuous functions that are integrable.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is justifying why $-1/x$ is the antiderivative you choose.

The problem is that the "constant of integration" only needs to be locally constant: the domain of your functions here include two disjoint intervals, and each one gets its own constant of integration. The complete set of antiderivatives to $1/x^2$ is all of the piecewise defined functions of the form

$$ \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{x} + C & x < 0 \\ -\frac{1}{x} + D & x > 0 \end{cases} $$

where $C$ and $D$ are any constants, and your "forgetting" method results in $-2 + D - C$.

In order to "make sense of this", you need to find some systematic reason to set $C=D$ here. There are surely classes of examples where you can find such a reason, but not in *full* generality.

Answer (score 0):

You already have explanations that take care of the singularity at zero. Here is another argument:

It is complete nonsense for the simple reason that you have a positive integrand and a negative end result. This goes against (one of) the (main) motivation(s) of integration, namely to represent area.

Comment: Right, that was the first thing I thought of... but still wanted to ask this question... who knows :) since people can make sense of the correspondence $1+2+3+... = -\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: Of course, then it depends on what one means by "make sense of"...